# how to use boolean when using form append in vuejs

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

i'm trying to send availability

```
          <input
            v-model="availability"
          />
        </div>
```

as a boolean but it keeps sending false to my database ,
this is my script , on default it returns false

```
<script>
export default {

  data() {
    return {
      availability: false
    };
  },

  methods: {
    async handleSubmit() {
      const formData = new FormData();
      formData.append("availability", this.availability);
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

[image]

this is my api

```
 product.avaliability = req.body.avaliability
```

it returns true in my console when i click the checkbox

```
 console.log(this.availability)
```

Comment: what evidence is there that availability _shouldn't_ be false?  you've not described how the form is actually used.  start at the beginning.  when `handleSubmit` first executes, if you `console.log(this.availability)` what is the value?

Comment: it returns true in my console

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check your spelling it should be availability not avaliability